# How can I implement a basic "Most Popular Post" script in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

There seem to be very few tutorials out there about how to write a PHP script to show the "Most Viewed" posts. I've found some scripts custom made for WordPress and haven't been able to get any of them to work for me. The rest are most popular php scripts for programmers.

I have table called `news` with the fields `id, count, timestamp, headline, img, text`.
I want to get the 5 most popular posts for the last week showing just number and headline.

How can I go about this?

Comment: What does the field `count` do? And yes, this shouldn't be a very difficult *query*.

Comment: Sure, you just +1 to a MySQL table storing all the view, then grab the top ones out to display whenever the page loads.

Comment: ok, of course :) just ORDER BY count DESC .... so when viewer open news_id.php it would add +1 to the count field?

Comment: That sounds appropriate (or you could put it in another lookup table). And then you can `LIMIT 0, 5` so you only get five results back.

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) is more useful than an English description alone of existing parts of the solution. For MySQL, this means give the table schemata using `CREATE TABLE` statements and sample data using `INSERT` statements. You'll also get more useful replies if you ask for help with a specific issue in implementing a particular solution. We're here to help, not do your work.

Comment: add a field to store number of clicks, then sort out the table by that field in descending, you will get most viewed posts.

Comment: outis - I know it´s best to post the code. I was just looking for help for a general solution which is odd isn´t visible onnline - I didn´t ask anyone to do it for me - And also it might help others to see my question on stachoverflow and the solution to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will grab 5 records from within the last week with the highest `count` value

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
FROM newsTable 
WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 5
";
```

**EDIT**

An easy way to increase the count field by 1 and update the timestamp

```
$sql = "
UPDATE yourtable 
SET count = count + 1, 
timestamp = NOW()
WHERE id = " . $post_id
```

Comment: `LIMIT 5` and `LIMIT 0, 5` and `LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0` are equivalent.

Comment: yes like 0,5.. hey cool this works :) but I manually inserted numbers in some rows of "count"... but how would the script on the article page which add +1 to the field?

Comment: @ypercube - I could be reading the docs wrong, but it states that `offset` is first if the `OFFSET` keyword is not used: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html (and I'm wondering if I am reading that wrong...)

Comment: @ypercube - Nevermind, I just confirmed they are equivalent. I was misinterpreting the docs.

Comment: @Ingpor - I added a sql statement that will increase your count and update the timestamp with a given post id

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to add a `count` (or `hits`) column:

```
ALTER TABLE news ADD count INTEGER
```

Then whenever you display the news, increment the appropriate count:

```
UPDATE news SET count = (count+1) WHERE id = X
```

Then just show the most popular news:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
```